# Socket.io - angular.js. - always disconnected with "ping timeout"

Tags: angularjs, socket.io

Trying to connect with Angular js + socket.io  to the server (Node.js - nestsJS)

I have both React and Angular app
in react app everything is work

in Angularjs I got always "ping timeout" and then it try to recconect - on the server I saw the connection and it pass the authentication flow.

when I going to the network tab(WS) I got my events after authenticated in the backend so it looks like its a client issue
so every ~30sec the console output disconnect + reason "ping timeout"

Angular code -socket service

```
        .factory('socket', socket);

    socket.$inject = ["$rootScope"];

    function socket($rootScope) {

        const options = {
                    transports:['websocket'],
                    // allowUpgrades: false,
      
                    query: {
                        token : "token",
                    },
                    forceNew: true
                }
        var socket = io.connect('/', { ...options, path: `/socket.io` });

        return {
            on: function(eventName, callback) {
                socket.on(eventName, function() {
                    var args = arguments;
                    $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                        callback.apply(socket, args);
                    });
                });
            },
            emit: function(eventName, data, callback) {
                socket.emit(eventName, data, function() {
                    var args = arguments;
                    $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                        if (callback) {
                            callback.apply(socket, args);
                        }
                    });
                })
            }
        };
```

controller:

```
     socket.on('connect', function (data) {
            console.log("connect")

        });
        socket.on('connection', function (data) {
            console.log("connect")

        });
        socket.on('disconnect', function (data) {
            console.log("disconnect")
            console.log(data)
        });

        socket.on('events-test', function (data) {
            console.log("test")
            console.log(data)
        })
```

in the network tab i can see the "events-test" events and it will create a new "ws" tab evrey reconnection

Comment: What version of socket.io do you use on client and or nodeJs Server ?

Comment: @MisterniceGuy hi , thanks 
server - > ( using @nestjs/platform-socket.io 6.11.11 based on  socket.io": "2.3.0")

client-  Socket.IO v4.0.0

Comment: i tried also client with ver 3.1.3 got the same ping timeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by change the socket-io client version to 2.3.0
Use socketio version 2 on the client side to match the server. 3 and 4 are incompatible with server v2

Comment: I had similar issues when using for example client > 3.x with server 2.x. I ultimately went to 4.x on both. Major change is that you will get cors issues on your client , but that's an easy fix as well as the fact that some stuff has been depreciated.